# how to zip files from a given directory in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, zip

I created a files in the directory

application/files_to_download

in files to download folder there are two files which are created dynamicaly
a.pdf
b.pdf

now I want to zip this two files from files_to_download folder
note:only file not the directory

i tried

```
$files = array('a.pdf', 'b.pdf');
            $zipname = 'zip_app_t.zip';
            $zip = new ZipArchive;
            $zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);
            foreach ($files as $file) {
            $zip->addFile($file);
            }
            $zip->close();
    header('Content-type: application/zip');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$zipname.'"');
```

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/libraries/zip.html this might help

Comment: This helped me $path = '/path/to/photo.jpg';

$this->zip->read_file($path);

// Download the file to your desktop. Name it "my_backup.zip"
$this->zip->download('my_backup.zip');

Answer (score 0):

```
    $path = "Your path";
    $this->load->library('zip');
    $this->zip->read_dir($path,FALSE);
    ob_end_clean();
    $this->zip->download('filename.zip');
```

Comment: give the path up to the directory in which your files are located. In my case i wrote  $path = 'salaryslips/' . $month_year.'/';

Comment: Please add some explanation to this code or it risks deletion.